# Is it possible to open a namespace provided by a Type Provider?

Tags: f#, type-providers

Is there any way to `open` a namespace of types provided by a [type provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156509.aspx) implementation?  I ask, because some of the generated type name paths are very long and ugly in code.  I have used type abbreviations to alleviate this, but obviously this is a manual process.  <s>The F# `open` keyword does not support this.  Is there another way?</s> *Update: as pointed out in the answer and comments this is wrong.  You can open a type provided namespace.  I had not realised I was looking at deeply nested types, not a namespace.*

Comment: Are you talking about namespaces, or provided types containing other types?  I'd have expected provided namespaces to work fine, but the issue is that you can only parameterize provided types, not namespaces, and there's no way to ``open`` a type.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @kvb.  I had not realised I was dotting through types (I'm using the Wsdl type provider which is paramterised).  I shall look closer next time.  Any thoughts on how I should edit the question, as I am clearly wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is tricky - parameterized type providers (like the standard SQL providers or the F# Data providers for XML and JSON) need to put all types that they generate (representing tables, XML nodes, etc) inside the main generated type. So all types that you might want to use are hidden somewhere as nested types of the main type (with parameters specified).

This makes sense - if you use the type provider with multiple parameters, the types generated for each configuration have to be separate.

As @kvb points out, you cannot `open` a nested type, but you can use type aliases to make this a bit less painful. For example, using F# Data, I can define an alias `R` that lets me access all the generated domain types with just two additional characters:

```
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data.1.1.10\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

type RssFeed = XmlProvider<"http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml">
type R = RssFeed.DomainTypes

let printTitle (itm:R.Item) = printfn "%A" itm.Title
```